# How to set chart height closer to bottom using AChartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

[image]

Refer to the image above. In AChartEngine, although Zoom Buttons are hidden using method setZoomButtonsVisible(false), it leaves a large space between the X-axis to the bottom.

How do I make the chart stick to the bottom? I have tried many methods without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple way to do this. Please see a few of them below:

- Set the height of the legend manually: `renderer.setLegendHeight(height);`
- Make the legend size itself to occupy the needed space: `renderer.setFitLegend(true);`
- Don't show the legend at all: `renderer.setShowLegend(false);`